# How to set static IP address on Window 8.1 Host with Hyper-V and Single network adapter

Tags: networking, windows-8, hyper-v, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows 8.1 Pro machine (not preview). In order to do Windows Phone 8 development, the emulators have to use the Hyper-V engine to run. When Hyper-V was installed it changed my network adapter settings for my ethernet card to utilizing the Hyper-V virtual switch, and disabled all the other items, such as IPv4, etc. It appears I can no longer set a static ip address on my box for my LAN, or at least it is not evident how to do it.

Articles that I have read suggest that I need two network adapters, but they seem to be geared towards a different type of infrastructure, which is different than what I am doing. I do not wish to purchase another network adapter. I simply want a static IP address on my box as my router is configured to route certain types of traffic to my box, and utilize Hyper-V just to run the Windows Phone emulators, but the emulators still have to access the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never truly directly resolved this issue directly with the adapter as the things that I tried, including setting the IP address of the vEthernet adapter seemed to create problems with other Virtual Adapters I had on my machine. As a result, I edited the settings on my router and had the router reserve the same ip address for my specific machine, using the MAC address for my adapter. I specifically have a Netgear Nighthawk router, but most modern routers should provide this functionality.

After implementing this solution I decided it was a preferable solution anyhow, as it guarantees my machine has the same IP address no matter what OS I boot in, as long as the OS is configured to use DHCP, and I do not need to configure each OS separately.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by setting DNS IP addresses along with the static IP (used Google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4). After I pressed OK to confirm the changes the yellow mark above the internet connection icon disappeared right away.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue as you were, I solved it by setting the static IP address in the vEthernet instead of the Ethernet.